# How to handle image with extension .nii.gz? Is it possible to convert them in grayscale format like (240,240)?

Tags: python, image, medical-imaging

I have always work with images with extensions .png, .jpg, .jpeg  Now, I have seen medical images with extension .nii.gz

I'm using python and I have read it with the following code:

```
path = "./Task01_BrainTumour/imagesTr"
path_list = glob.glob(path+'/*.gz') #list with all paths of image.nii.gz
    
img = nib.load(path_list[0]).get_data() #load a single image
```

Now the image is an `array of float32` and it has the following shape `(240, 240, 155, 4)`. I have read online that `(240, 240, 155, 4)` indicates that the image has size `(240,240)`, `155` indicates the depth of the image object, namely there are `155` layers in every image object. However, this information related to the layer/depth is not clear to me, what does it mean that an image has some layers? Finally, `4` indicates the channel of the image.

I would like to convert these images in the classical format (240,240,3) for rgb or (240,240) in grayscale. I don't know if it is possible to do that.

Comment: While i got no idea what `nii` is, the `.gz` suffix suggests gzip  compressed file. You may want `gunzip` it first

Comment: You've not told us where you have been to, but from http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/NII points to https://nifti.nimh.nih.gov for all the gory details.

That first page, also has links to C and python code.

Comment: Are you able to open the file in some medical image viewer? If so, at least you will have a better idea on the 155 and 4. I guess 155 is the number of frames or slices, it could be a short video clip, or it could be a 3D volume (CT or MRI)

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there.

It looks like you're using the Brain Tumours data from the [Medical Segmentation Decathlon](http://medicaldecathlon.com/), and [NiBabel](https://nipy.org/nibabel/) to read the images. You can install e.g. [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) to save the JPGs.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
from skimage import io


def to_uint8(data):
    data -= data.min()
    data /= data.max()
    data *= 255
    return data.astype(np.uint8)


def nii_to_jpgs(input_path, output_dir, rgb=False):
    output_dir = Path(output_dir)
    data = nib.load(input_path).get_fdata()
    *_, num_slices, num_channels = data.shape
    for channel in range(num_channels):
        volume = data[..., channel]
        volume = to_uint8(volume)
        channel_dir = output_dir / f'channel_{channel}'
        channel_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
        for slice in range(num_slices):
            slice_data = volume[..., slice]
            if rgb:
                slice_data = np.stack(3 * [slice_data], axis=2)
            output_path = channel_dir / f'channel_{channel}_slice_{slice}.jpg'
            io.imsave(output_path, slice_data)
```